# Why sonar requires binary files (sonar.binaries)

Tags: sonarqube

Why sonar requires binary files (sonar.binaries)? How it uses binaries to do what ever it does with the binaries?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sonar.binaries` is a deprecated property : you should now use `sonar.java.binaries`

This property is used by the java analysis (so I'm assuming you are analyzing java code).

The analysis is done file by file at source level, and in order to properly do a semantic analysis the java analyzer reads information of external dependencies from the `.class` files.

Concretely this is how it works : While analyzing `A.java` which declares :

```
class A {
   B b;
}
```

The java analyzer will construct semantic model of class A and for external dependencies look into bytecode for `B.class` to complete its semantic analysis.

Why is it doing that ? in order to solve type of expressions to have a more accurate analysis. (ie: answering the question : What is the type of b.foo(): we need to find out the definition of foo() method).

This is a deliberate choice of implementation to rely on bytecode for every external dependencies, even if we have the source for them.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that was helpful!!..:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice explanation

Comment: Is possible to avoid this kind of analysis and only analyze java files?

Comment: Yes, you can but it will make the analysis far less powerful, to not say useless

Comment: Why is this a case with only Java and not languages like C for example?
I have a project where 10k+ java source files are there, now I wish to have sonar run over it on every code change. I feel building the code base everytime even for a small change will be kind of less productive. Is there any workaround for this?