# Why is Gradle building my Java project, when I just call für a SonarQube analysis?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am wondering why Gradle builds my project, when I call Sonarqube for static code analysis:

`./gradlew sonarqube`

How can I prevent Gradle from building the whole project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonarqube does not only analyze the source code. It also produces some reports on code coverage of tests. Therefore tests must be run and all your code needs to be compiled.

If your project is in Java, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989414/why-sonar-requires-binary-files-sonar-binaries) also explains that Sonarqube performs semantic analysis based on `.class` file

Comment: See also Sonarqube official documentation :https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle . In the last section "Task dependencies": it is stated that *sonarqube* task has a task dependency on *test* task (when Java plugin is applied)

Comment: I don't like it that way. They could have split this in 7 different tasks, where you can select, which of them is executed, and which of them is not executed.

Comment: @ErdincAy Did you ever find a way to suppress the building of the project?  I also find this behaviour very undesirable.  The project binaries and reports were already built by earlier CI steps.  SonarQube seems to assume most basic use case.

Comment: @ChrisHatton Hi Chris, i am sorry to say, that I did not find a way to suppress the building of the project, due to the technical reason, that SonarQube Runner needs the Class-Files to perform an analysis.